# nothing gets logged at logging for a 500 error (Django)

Tags: django, logging

I have copied pasted this at the settings.py (but done nothing else)
I am in production and debug is set to False because I have read that his how you have to do it
I have placed the log file in a place where the owner of the application can write, yet nothing is written.
The error comes after I try to save a form. The form has 3 tables, address, property and pictures. address and property are saved perfectly, pictures saves nothing.
The app works in my local computer perfectly. Without any reason, it fails here in production. I copy pasted this but it doesn't save anything to the file

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        # Include the default Django email handler for errors
        # This is what you'd get without configuring logging at all.
        'mail_admins': {
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'level': 'ERROR',
             # But the emails are plain text by default - HTML is nicer
            'include_html': True,
        },
        # Log to a text file that can be rotated by logrotate
        'logfile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'filename': '/home/bills/alvar/myapp/dapp.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # Again, default Django configuration to email unhandled exceptions
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        # Might as well log any errors anywhere else in Django
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        # Your own app - this assumes all your logger names start with "myapp."
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'WARNING', # Or maybe INFO or DEBUG
            'propagate': False
        },
    },
}
```

UPDATE:

I must be one of the most knowledgeable programmers on stackoverflow as 90% of the questions I ask can never find an answer. By the way, sentry.io is also clueless, can't find any issue despite the whopping 500 server error that I have.

Comment: Hi, your question is too broad and missing specific details. Here is few questions that might help: 1. where and how the production environment is deployed? 2. does your application containerized? 3. did you able to ready other logs?